# How do I write this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem as to how I can only get the students, in which position he/she is running for with the highest accumulated votes in my query filtered by its organization Id.

this is the sqlfiddle link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd3d76/3

This is the query that I have constructed so far:

```
Select c.c_id, s.s_fname, count(r.c_id)
from results r, candidates c, student s,positioning p, organization o 
where r.c_id = c.c_id 
AND c.sid = s.sid 
AND c.pos_id = p.pos_id 
AND o.org_id = c.org_id 
AND o.org_id = 1
GROUP BY c.c_id;
```

From the output given from the link I've provided, I only need to see:

John, President, 2   -> since he is the one who got the highest vote the presidential position

Chris, Vice President, 3

Ciel, Secretary, 3

thanks to those who will help . . . and also to those who just wanted to view my question. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd3d76/19

```
SELECT src.c_id, src.s_fname, c 
FROM (
    SELECT c.c_id, s.s_fname, count(r.c_id) AS c, p.pos_id
    FROM results r, candidates c, student s,positioning p, organization o 
    WHERE r.c_id = c.c_id 
    AND c.sid = s.sid 
    AND c.pos_id = p.pos_id 
    AND o.org_id = c.org_id 
    AND o.org_id = 1
    GROUP BY c.c_id
) src
GROUP BY src.pos_id;
```

Eventually you can add:

```
HAVING MAX(src.c);
```

Answer (score 2):

This query uses variables to number each candidate for their position in descending order of vote count (i.e. the candidates with the most votes for their position are #1, second most votes #2, etc). It then only keeps #1 candidates.

```
select * from (
    select *,
        @rownum := if(@prevposid = pos_id,@rownum+1,1) rownum,
        @prevposid := pos_id
    from (
        select c.c_id, s.s_fname, count(r.c_id), c.pos_id
        from results r, candidates c, student s,positioning p, organization o 
        where r.c_id = c.c_id 
        and c.sid = s.sid 
        and c.pos_id = p.pos_id 
        and o.org_id = c.org_id 
        and o.org_id = 1
        group by c.c_id
        order by p.pos_id, count(*) desc
    ) t1 
) t1 where rownum = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abc9f0/1